# Convert.ToDateTime , any way to depict month and year fields C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following wonderfully unreliable statement:

```
  string LastsuccessfuldownloadDateTime = "04.07.2009 19:21:36"
  DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(LastsuccessfuldownloadDateTime);
```

Is it possible to depict the day and month fields explicitly in the conversion?
Because my month and day fields are getting swapped....

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact():

```
// for European format (day followed by month)
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(LastsuccessfuldownloadDateTime , 
                                      "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```