# Format of Convert.ToDateTime(string) method

Tags: c#, .net

When we execute
`Convert.ToDateTime('08/01/2014')` how does it convert to 1-Aug-2014 (ignore the format) and not to 8-Jan-2014?

As far as I saw, there is no mention of any format for the string parameter that is being passed on to this method.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: determined by the server settings if culture is not defined.

Comment: If you don't specify a culture your current culture is used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert.ToDateTime , any way to depict month and year fields C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398432/convert-todatetime-any-way-to-depict-month-and-year-fields-c)

Comment: @EugenePodskal This is not a duplicate. This question ask _why_ `Convert.ToDateTime` converts this string as `1-Aug-2014` not `8-Jan-2014`.

Comment: @SonerGönül I have retracted the vote, but these two questions are far too close(at least in their current form) as for me. Maybe there should be created some canonical answer for such month-in-place-of-day problems?

Comment: Soner Gonul, I was looking for this! CurrentCulture was something that I have not heard of. Thanks :)

Comment: @Salihdeen Could you please share what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Comment: @EugenePodskal There is no (and shouldn't be) _canonical_ answer for this kind of questions because it is totally depends on cultures and which date patterns they have as a standard.

Comment: @SonerGönül My `CurrentCulture` is "en-US"!

Comment: @Salihdeen Updated my answer now, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is `Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2014")` not `Convert.ToDateTime('08/01/2014')`. Strings are represents with double quotes, not single quotes.

`Convert.ToDateTime(string)` method uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) as an `IFormatProvider` by default. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#fce604498e2f810b);

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value)
{
     if (value == null)
         return new DateTime(0);
     return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

And `DateTime.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#3dcde4b72349960c) as;

```
public static DateTime Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return (DateTimeParse.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider), DateTimeStyles.None));
}
```

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the
>   DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture.
>   **The value argument must contain the representation of a date and time
>   in one of the formats described in the DateTimeFormatInfo topic.**

So, what is *`DateTimeFormatInfo` topic* here exactly? It is the `DateTimeFormatInfo`'s information with [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns.aspx).

Most probably your current thread culture has a `MM/dd/yyyy` not `dd/MM/yyyy` (or which character is your [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture` because  [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me current culture or specified culture date separator*) as a [standard date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can see all standard date and time formats of your `CurrentCulture` with;

```
var patterns = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
                           DateTimeFormat.
                           GetAllDateTimePatterns();
foreach (var format in patterns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Let me give you an example; my current thread culture is Turkish (`tr-TR`). And it has `dd.MM.yyyy` as a standard date and time format.

That's why when I write `Convert.ToDateTime("02.01.2014")` in my code, it parses this string as *January 2nd* not *February 1st*.

> @SonerGönül My CurrentCulture is "en-US"! –  Salihdeen 3 mins ago

Exactly as I said, your `en-US` has `MM/dd/yyyy` but not `dd/MM/yyyy` as a standard date and time format. That's why your `08/01/2014` string parsed with `MM/dd/yyyy` pattern not `dd/MM/yyyy`.

```
var patterns = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").
                       DateTimeFormat.
                       GetAllDateTimePatterns();
foreach (var format in patterns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Result will be;

```
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy <-- HERE!
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
MMMM dd, yyyy
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy
dd MMMM, yyyy
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm
M/d/yyyy HH:mm
M/d/yy h:mm tt
M/d/yy hh:mm tt
M/d/yy H:mm
M/d/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm
MM/dd/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
yy/MM/dd h:mm tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm
yy/MM/dd HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
dd-MMM-yy h:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm
M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy H:mm:ss
M/d/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd
MMMM dd
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
h:mm tt
hh:mm tt
H:mm
HH:mm
h:mm:ss tt
hh:mm:ss tt
H:mm:ss
HH:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM, yyyy
MMMM, yyyy
```

Answer (score 3):

[No mention?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx)

> If *value* is not **null**, the return value is the result of invoking the [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) method on *value* using the formatting information in a [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) object that is initialized for the current culture.

Comment: Thanks, Rawling. I just realised that this question has been silly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string datetime, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

eg:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08-01-2014", "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: Wait.. what? `en-US` culture? o.O I think you missed the question completely.

Comment: This is just an example. I have no idea what is his CurrentCulture

Comment: or CultureInfo.InvariantCulture